# PHP arrays assign value then get variable value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sorry for this beginner question. My problem is that I would like to get the value of the variable name assigned in the array. For instance like this:

```
$fruits = array($apple, $mango, $banana);
```

And then I am assigning the elements in the array same values.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) { 
    $fruits[$i] = "fruit";
}
```

When I want to print the apple value in the array I would do:

```
echo $fruits[0];
```

But what I want is that to print the value of apple in the array using:

```
echo $apple;
```

How would I do this? Sorry beginner here..

Comment: try this print_r(get_defined_vars());

Comment: Thank you for answering! Is it possible just to echo the value in the array? Like echo $apple and then getting the value?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You're overwriting the `$apple` item in your `$fruits` array with `"fruit"` so naturally the value of `$apple` is gone? Are you trying to add items to the array?

Comment: I think you're a little confused on the purpose of arrays. You can achieve what you're doing by just assigning values directly to the fruit.

Comment: Why not do an associative array if you want to use "apple": `$fruits = array("apple"=>$apple,"mango"=>$mango); echo $fruits['apple'];` I assume it's for readability??

Comment: @Rasclatt Thanks for answering! If possible how would I do assigning values using foreach?

Comment: Yes use a `foreach()` to retain the `key` name.

Comment: @Huey What I am trying to do is to assign the variable names ($apple, $mango, $banana) the same values. And then I would like to access the variable names ($apples, etc..) and then assign it into another name by calling the variable name.

Comment: @Scopet Yes I'm confused sorry for that.

Comment: @Rasclatt If possible how would I do that? Is it something like:
foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) {
 $fruits[$key] = "fruits";
}

Comment: Yes, `$key` will retain the names like `apple` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,so what you are doing is incorrect to begin with.

```
$apple = "apple";
$mango = "mango";
$banana ="banana";

$fruits = array($apple, $mango, $banana);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) { 
    $fruits[$i] = "fruit";
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fruits);
```

What you have done in your for loop is to override the values of the array. So when you do the print_r you will get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fruit
    [1] => fruit
    [2] => fruit
)
```

If you want to store whether it is a fruit or vegetable (and i wonder if it is the case, since your array name is 'fruits'), however if you do want to do that, then you should use an associative array:

```
 $cabbage= 'cabbage';
 $stuffIEat = array($apple => 'fruit', 
                    $mango => 'fruit', 
                    $banana =>'fruit',
                    $cabbage => 'vegetable');
```

Now when you want to see what kind of stuff apple is, you do:

```
echo $stuffIEat[$apple]; //prints fruit
echo $stuffIEat[$cabbage]; //prints vegetable
```

Now if you want to print all the fruits that you eat, you do:

`print_r(array_keys($stuffIEat,'fruit'));`

This will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => mango
    [2] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative.

```
<?php
$fruits = array(
    "apple" => $apple, 
    "mango" => $mango, 
    "banana" => $banana);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) { 
    $fruits[$key] = "fruit";
}

echo $fruits['mango'];
```